# What does a HTML tag consist of?

Tags: html

Is the HTML tag just the < and > symbols or does the name inside the tag also count a part of the html tag? What does a HTML tag consist of? What is the word/name inside the HTML tag formally called?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Tag

Comment: There are wayyy to many questions in this single question. *"What is the word/name inside the HTML tag formally called?"* - do you want a list of every single expanded tag name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tag consists of a `<`, the tag name, zero or more space-separated attributes (which in turn consist of a name and a quote-surrounded value separated by a `=`), and a `>`. See [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element) for more details.